# Long title with no spaces flows into the sidebar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, title

When [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590655/system-web-configuration-webconfigurationmanager-openwebconfiguration) is shown in a [review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5228129) its title flows into the sidebar because the title doesn't contain any spaces.

[image]

If there is a simple solution and that page is touched can this be fixed?

This is repro-ed in IE11, Chrome and Firefox  on Windows 7.

Comment: Yikes, not a single space in the title! Guess they didn't cover all the corners yet. I'm tempted to edit to "fix" this, lol.

Comment: I view this as a feature, drawing immediate attention to the fact that the title is *probably* bad and needs editing.

Comment: @Geobits As soon as this get tagged status-declined we re-tag it as faq. *Should I edit titles that screw up the layout of the site?* Answer: *Yes*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've modified the `h1` container of the question title adding `overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;` which creates a nice "trailing off with ..." effect for long titles such as the one in your example. It'll be live in the next build (> rev `2014.7.9.2359`).

Comment: Verified and fixed in rev 2014.7.10.1696 on SO...