# Long.strings.with.no.spaces in titles overflow into the right column

Tags: bug, design, badges, title

On an individual Badges page (for example, [Promoter](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/220/promoter)), when a title includes a long string with no spaces, it overflows into the right column (where the user cards are):

[image]

It's worse on mobile (Chrome for Android):

[image]

Can this be fixed?

Comment: I don't think this is confined to just the badges page.

Comment: @Luuklag: I haven't checked elsewhere.. Could you provide some links/screenshots of other occurrences? I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Another related question: [Long title with no spaces flows into the sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235164/long-title-with-no-spaces-flows-into-the-sidebar). This was an issue in the review queues and was fixed back in 2014.

Comment: imo it's [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330929/moderator-revision-redaction-approval-display-issue) too, the text was spanning the right sidebar.

Comment: It does recognise a dash as a place to wrap to the next line, if somehow the dot could ve added to that this would be fixed.

Comment: @Luuklag: Looks like it *only* wraps when there is a dash. For all the other characters (`.`, `_`, `+`, etc.), the whole string is treated as one word, causing an overflow.